# jquery validation not working with suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have some form on my page and jquery validation and it's not working when I pick some value from field suggestions.

```
customForm.validate({
  onkeyup: function(element) {
    $(element).valid();
  },
  errorElement: 'p',
  errorClass: "error",
  rules: {
    phoneNumber: {required: true, minLength: 10}
  },
  errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    error.appendTo(element.parent());
  }
});
```

Is it possible to add validation when suggestion is selected?

**UPD:** Added some custom validation for form inputs. I guess for now jquery validation doesn't have functionality to do this.

```
$("#customForm input").on('input', function() { ... });
```

Comment: Could you come up with complete code to replicate this or better try creating a fiddle for this?

Comment: First enter 1 letter for example and then select from your list of suggestions something longer then 5 symbols, error still showed. If you don't have suggestions enter few times some words to the field I think they should be saved to suggestions list. http://jsfiddle.net/aeho1v4q/3/

Comment: What are you talking about regarding "suggestion"?  I see nothing called `suggestion` in your code.  As already requested in the first comment, **where is the relevant HTML to reproduce this problem**?  Please EDIT your OP to include *all relevant* code.

Comment: BTW - it's `minlength`, not `minLength`... this misspelling could break the plugin.

Comment: Regarding your jsFiddle, why are you using jQuery 1.5 and jQuery Validate 1.7? Those versions are more than 5 years old.